# Calling from another windows form issue in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datareader

I have a button on Form1 which has this code

```
       // hide main form
        this.Hide();

        // show other form
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();

        // close application
        this.Close();
```

Now on Form2 load i have this code which do not show me result,although reader has values.
It shows me Form2 with empty textfields

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM test;";
            SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();

            // Call Read before accessing data. 
            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                t1.Text = reader1.GetString(0);
                t2.Text = reader1.GetString(1);


            }

            // Call Close when done reading.
            reader1.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint to see what you get?

Comment: Where you execute this code?

Comment: yes,it has values in reader but do not assign to textfields...when it reach there it execute Form1's button again

Comment: While loop says read until last row of fetched records. There is possibility that index 0 and 1 are empty in the last traversal of the reader.

Comment: reader1.GetString(0); here value in table is int..is that a problem?

Comment: there is only one row...id=1 and test='testing' where i use reader1.GetString(1); then working but how i can get id?

Comment: try this instead `reader1[0].ToString(); reader1[1].ToString();`

Comment: Where are those TextBoxes (if that's what they are) in Form1 or Form2? Where is the code, in form2.Load??

Comment: It is better to wrap your reader1 in a using statement: `using (SqlDataReader reader1 = command.ExecuteReader()) { ... }` you should also do this for `SqlCommand command` so that these things will get automatically closed (even if an exception is thrown before the code is completed).

Answer (score 1):

Avoid this :

```
            t1.Text = reader1.GetString(0);
            t2.Text = reader1.GetString(1);
```

Don't mention the type , because when you use this query

```
select * from test ;
```

and then you change the type of your columns , you will get bad results.

So, you may try this  :

```
            t1.Text = reader1[0].ToString();
            t2.Text = reader1[1].ToString();
```